# PHP cURL: upload file from form to remote API?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file on a form on my site, and then pass it on to a remote API.

This is my PHP:

```
$fields = array(
    'file'=>$_FILES["mediaupload"],
    'username'=>urlencode($_POST["username"]),
    'password'=>urlencode($_POST["password"]),
    'latitude'=>urlencode($_POST["latitude"]),
    'longitude'=>urlencode($_POST["longitude"]),
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
$url = my_url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
```

At the moment I keep getting error messages that the file could not be processed properly. The API expects all fields as POST strings except the file, which it expects in binary.

I know it's going to be tough to debug this for you guys without access to the remote API, but am I doing anything **obviously** wrong, or should this work?

Many thanks.

Comment: does your API have a documentation? they should tell you how to use cURL with it

Comment: Not sure, but is there a setting in php.ini to enable curl? Check phpinfo() to see if it's enabled or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File upload using curl does not work like this. You need to first save the file locally using php's `move_uploaded_file` then get the path to file. In the fields add this,

```
$fields = array(
    'file'=>"@/path/to/myfile.ext",
    'username'=>urlencode($_POST["username"]),
    'password'=>urlencode($_POST["password"]),
    'latitude'=>urlencode($_POST["latitude"]),
    'longitude'=>urlencode($_POST["longitude"]),
);
```

Also,
I'm not sure if fields array needs to be converted to string to be used as postfields. According to manual it can be an array() directly.

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    The full data to
>   post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To
>   post a file, prepend a filename with @
>   and use the full path. The filetype
>   can be explicitly specified by
>   following the filename with the type
>   in the format ';type=mimetype'. This
>   parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like
>   'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an
>   array with the field name as key and
>   field data as value. If value is an
>   array, the Content-Type header will be
>   set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, files thats passed to this option with the @ prefix must be in
>   array form to work.

Comment: To make your example work with the OP's situation, you'd need `'file' => '@' . $_FILES['mediaupload']['tmp_name']`, to point CURL at the temporary file where the upload was place on his server.

Comment: Very helpful, i was just going to post a similar question. So can I use the temporary path and specify a mime-type at the same time (as in 'file' => '@'.$_FILES['mediaupload']['tmp_name'].';type='.$_FILES['mediaupload']['type']; ?