# Construct a PHP POST request with binary data

Tags: php, html, api, file-upload

I'm trying to construct a PHP POST request that includes some binary data, following on from [a previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428282/php-curl-upload-file-from-form-to-remote-api). The data is being submitted to this API call: http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/#addphoto

This is my PHP code:

```
$file = $_FILES['mediaupload'];
$file_field="@$file[tmp_name]";
$fields = array(
    'mediaupload'=>$file_field,
    'username'=>urlencode($_POST["username"]),
    'password'=>urlencode($_POST["password"]),
    'latitude'=>urlencode($_POST["latitude"]),
    'longitude'=>urlencode($_POST["longitude"]),
    'datetime'=>urlencode($_POST["datetime"]),
    'category'=>urlencode($_POST["category"]),
    'metacategory'=>urlencode($_POST["metacategory"]),
    'caption'=>urlencode($_POST["description"])
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
echo 'FIELDS STRING: ' . $fields_string;
$url = 'https://www.cyclestreets.net/api/addphoto.json?key=$key';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
```

This is what my PHP file outputs:

```
FIELDS STRING: mediaupload=%40%2Fprivate%2Fvar%2Ftmp%2FphpHjfkRP&username=testing&password=testing&latitude=auto&longitude=auto&datetime=auto&category=cycleparking&metacategory=good&caption=
API RESPONSE: {"request":{"datetime":"1309886656"},"error":{"code":"unknown","message":"The photo was received successfully, but an error occurred while processing it."},"result":{}}
```

I believe this means that everything else about the request is OK, apart from the format of the binary data. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You want to send the file from $_FILES['mediaupload']?? But you never read that file, do you? This `$file_field="@$file[tmp_name]";` should be `$file_field = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);` or am I just too confused? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURL can accept a raw array of key=>value pairs for POST fields. There's no need to do all that urlencode() and http_build_query() stuff. Most likely the `@` in the array is being mangled into `%40`, so CURL doesn't see it as a file upload attempt.

```
$fields = array(
    'mediaupload'=>$file_field,
    'username'=> $_POST["username"),
    etc...

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
```

Comment: Passing the value of $_POST["username"] directly to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS data opens you up to an attack where "@/path/to/file" is specified by the browser in the "username" field. That will allow browser-specified filenames be fetched off the server's hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

The [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function generates a URL encoded query string which means that the "@file.ext" is URL encoded in the output as a string and cURL doesn't know that you're trying to upload a file.

My advice would be not to include the file to upload in the `http_build_query` call and included manually in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

```
$file = $_FILES['mediaupload'];
$file_field="@$file[tmp_name]";
$fields = array(
    'username'=>urlencode($_POST["username"]),
    'password'=>urlencode($_POST["password"]),
    'latitude'=>urlencode($_POST["latitude"]),
    'longitude'=>urlencode($_POST["longitude"]),
    'datetime'=>urlencode($_POST["datetime"]),
    'category'=>urlencode($_POST["category"]),
    'metacategory'=>urlencode($_POST["metacategory"]),
    'caption'=>urlencode($_POST["description"])
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
echo 'FIELDS STRING: ' . $fields_string;
$url = 'https://www.cyclestreets.net/api/addphoto.json?key=$key';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'mediaupload=' . $file_field . '&' . $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
```